# In GitHub for Windows, why can't I see all of my commits to the current branch in the current branch's history?

Tags: github-for-windows

I'm using the official GitHub for Windows client (http://windows.github.com/). I have been steadily committing changes to the branch "modeling-users", but I am unable to see many of my recent changes in the history for the current branch. I can see these commits by entering "git log" at the command prompt. I also looked at the commit history for this branch on the GitHub website. It shows the same incomplete commit history. Why isn't it showing all of my commits?

Image here: http://tinypic.com/r/maza7o/6

Comment: It takes some time to get the changes reflected on history tab of github online platform . Try again after sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As anonymous user [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099473/in-github-for-windows-why-cant-i-see-all-of-my-commits-to-the-current-branch-i#comment16170622_12099473), GitHub for Windows can take time to reflect updates to repositories. The commits will eventually appear in GitHub for Windows.